# REGEXP_REPLACE function in redshift to replace the stuff() function that replaces the second character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have this STUFF() function that I want to replace to make it work in redshift.

```
WHEN '1' THEN STUFF((select E010_SERIAL_NBR from vars), 2, 1, 'A')
```

I know there is a REGEXP_REPLACE function that can do this but I can't figure out the expression.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is hard to understand. Can you possibly Edit your question and provide an example of some inputs and what what outputs you would like to receive?

Comment: Hi John,
Basically, what I am looking for is a regular expression that I can use to get the 2nd character in a string and replace the character using the REGEXP_REPLACE function in redshift.
For eg: E010_SERIAL_NBR  = 1BCD1HJKLMON56UI  will change to 1ACD1HJKLMON56UI

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to **replace the second character of a string**.

I couldn't figure out how to do that with a Regex expression, but you could use:

```
SELECT LEFT(E010_SERIAL_NBR, 1) || 'A' || SUBSTRING(E010_SERIAL_NBR, 3, 999)
```

You could create a [user-defined function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) to create your own `STUFF()` expression. It would be something like:

```sql
create function f_stuff (text, text)
  returns text
stable
as $$
  SELECT LEFT($1, 1) || $2 || SUBSTRING($1, 3, 999)
$$ language sql;
```

Then call it with: `f_stuff(E010_SERIAL_NBR, 'A')`

Or, you could write the function to accept the positional parameters too.